# High availability database switchover

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

I have a database in a high availability group with two nodes and one listener.

Several times a week, I have a problem with switchovers. The message I get is:

> Stopped listening on virtual network name ''. No user action is required.

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure is this the only message, is their no disconnection message in errorlog

Comment: I have seen this happening when a state change occurs. Check the cluster logs / Windows event logs for more details. There should be messages pre this message in the error log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your cluster tries multiple times to attempt a failover and it maxes out on the failover threshold value, an error that you described occurs. Basically it gives up and goes into a failed/offline state and stops listening on Virtual Network Name. To find the RCA of your issue, you need to identify the errors that occurred prior to this error. Let's us know what you see and then we can further dig into issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that a scheduled Job is attempting some big insert that floods one of the databases and when the CPU rises the nodes switches over.

Thank you for your interest to help :)